# Why can't I import properties by brace from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I defined a javascript file as below:

```
export default {
  parseOptions: {
    tolerant: true,
    raw: true,
    tokens: true,
    range: true,
    comment: true,
  },
  syntaxType: {
    callback: 'callback',
    promise: 'promise',
    await: 'await',
  },
};
```

I use below code to import it in other files:

```
import { syntaxType } from './options';
...
synaxType.callback
```

I get an error that `synaxType` is not defined when I use it. However if I change to below code it will work fine:

```
import options from './options';
options.synaxType.callback
```

I wonder what wrong with my previous import. Do I need to configure anything for that? Below is my babel configuration:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015"],
    "stage-0",
    "react",
    "react-boilerplate"
  ],

  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `synaxType` is not the same as `syntaxType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of exports, default exports and named exports. Default exports don't require a name, whereas named exports do.

---

Here's how to `export` a default value

```
export default "apple";
```

Here's how to `import` a default value

```
import iCanNameThisWhateverSinceItsADefaultExport from "./apple_module";
```

---

Here's how to `export` a named value

```
export const apple = "apple";
```

Here's how to `import` a named value

```
export {apple} from "./apple_module";
```

---

If you want to have named access to `syntaxType`, you have two options:

If you leave it how it is, you simply need to change your `import` statement to:

```
import options from "./options";
const {syntaxType, parseOptions} = options;
// or access properties normally via (i.e.) options.syntaxType
```

Or you can make `syntaxType` and `parseOptions` named exports:

```
export const parseOptions = {
    tolerant: true,
    raw: true,
    tokens: true,
    range: true,
    comment: true,
  };

export const syntaxType = {
    callback: 'callback',
    promise: 'promise',
    await: 'await',
  };
```

And `import` them with

```
import {syntaxType, parseOptions} from "options";
```

It's simply a syntax issue. Once you understand the syntax, you'll should be good to go with imports/exports. Read all about [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) statements in the excellent MDN docs.

Comment: Don't forget  `import {apple as iCanNameThisWhateverIWantSinceItsAnAliasedNamedExport} …` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how the `default` works, you don't actually need to assign a name to it. If you want to use curly braces, you must set up up without the default like:

```
export var options = {
  parseOptions: {
    tolerant: true,
    raw: true,
    tokens: true,
    range: true,
    comment: true,
  },
  syntaxType: {
    callback: 'callback',
    promise: 'promise',
    await: 'await',
  },
};
```

Then you can

```
import { options } from './options';
options.syntaxType
```

Or

```
export var syntaxType = {
  callback: 'callback',
  promise: 'promise',
  await: 'await',
}
```

Comment: You're right about `default` but your code is wrong. You don't declare the var, and you're exporting the wrong object.

Comment: @loganfsmyth you're right, I wrote it in a hurry. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
import options from './options';
```

Will presume `options` is the default exported object. That is why `options.synaxType.callback` works.

The syntax

```
import { syntaxType } from './options';
```

Needs `syntaxType` to have been an exported member, such as:

```
export const syntaxType = {
    callback: 'callback',
    promise: 'promise',
    await: 'await',
};
```

If the above construct were present at the module, then that syntax would work.

Comment: Complete explanation and more info at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import